# How to randomly choose a number of rectangles to change colour

Tags: java

i want my program to randomly change the colour of around 50% of the rectangles within my grid, this is done using jframe.

i have an array with the length of the board and i want 50% of these numbers to be blue.

FALSE = grey

TRUE = blue

Note: this is within paint method using Graphics g

```
    grid = new boolean[board.length];

    Random r = new Random();    
    for(int i = 1;i <grid.length;i++){
        int rand = r.nextInt(i);
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use the getBoolean() method instead of getInt(int) to get an approximate 50/50 mix of the two colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the number of squares on the board and multiply by the target percent.
Assume 8x8 board, so 64 squares * .50 = 32.
I would create a List of all the rectangles.
Begin a loop.  Generate a random number from 0 to the size of the rectangle list.  Remove that position and make it blue.  End loop if all 32 rectangles are identified.

//Pseudo code

```
java.util.Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> rectangles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
{
  rectangles.add(i);
}
//Fill the rectangles
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
  int position = random.nextInt(rectangles.size());
  Integer toConvert = rectangles.remove(position);
  //perform operation to make toConvert blue.
  grid[toConvert] = true;
}
```